# Why does Community occasionally bump an unmodified entry?

Tags: discussion

I remember when [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/57651/8610) was first asked. I also remember it getting "modified" by Community before, and it has now been "modified" again. In both cases, no modifications appear to have been made; neither question nor answer was edited, and the question's tags remain intact.

Is there an explanation for this phenomena?

Comment: (Formerly, such questions did not include a banner announcing their bumpage.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Community will occasionally bump old questions with an unupvoted answer to the top of the list.

[Community ♦ seems to be bumping new questions more frequently than usual](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184485/community-seems-to-be-bumping-new-questions-more-frequently-than-usual/184511#184511)

> ...posts eligible for bumping have gone at least 30 days with no activity, have at least one answer scoring 0 and none scoring more than that, and no accepted answer (also, they can't be locked or closed).

(HT [Dan Henderson](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/users/23127/dan-henderson))

Comment: I think it also has to have no answer marked as accepted

Comment: I'm not able to suggest an edit to your answer through the UI, so: I suggest adding this quotation from the answer you linked to. `...posts eligible for bumping have gone at least 30 days with no activity, have at least one answer scoring 0 and none scoring more than that, and no accepted answer (also, they can't be locked or closed).`